# Changing assert statement to remove "== True" according to flake8 E712 produces error

Tags: python, python-3.x, assert, flake8

I am trying to write a pytest of the form

```
import numpy as np
import pytest

def test(blah):
    # ...
    assert (np.isclose(computed_value, expected_value, atol = 0.001, rtol = 0) == True), 
    "error message"
```

The pytests pass, but once I try to commit to GitLab, I get the following message and the commit fails to go through.

```
>  flake8...................................................................Failed
- hook id: flake8
- exit code: 1
  E712 comparison to True should be 'if cond is True:' or 'if cond:
```

Replacing the above assert by

```
assert if np.isclose(computed_value, expected_value, atol = 0.001, rtol = 0) is True,"Error message"
```

does not help either.

Further,

```
assert (np.isclose(computed_value, expected_value, atol = 0.001, rtol = 0) is True), 
        "error message"
```

causes my pytest to fail! How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the original code was not testing what you expect -- `==` in `numpy` is a *projection* (meaning `numpy.array([1, 2, 3]) == True => numpy.array([True, False, False])`

`numpy.isclose` is also a projection of sorts, returning an array with values for each comparison -- your original assertion only passed because a numpy array is "truthy" -- not that every value was close within the tolerance

you probably want to use `numpy.all` to validate that everything was "`isclose`" --

```py
assert numpy.all(numpy.isclose(...))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's something to be fixed on my part. But even after fixing, would you say that the == True is syntactically incorrect? (One of the answers suggests removing the == True part completely).

Comment: it's _usually_ a mistake to use `== True` -- there are some exceptions to this but I don't believe this particular numpy case is one of them (since you actually want `numpy.all`)

Answer (score -1):

> `E712 comparison to True should be 'if cond is True:' or 'if cond:`

This message is misleading in this context, because it shows an example of a condition that is used in an `if` statement.

It caused you to write

> ```
> assert if np.isclose( ...
> ```

But you are using the condition in an `assert` statement, not in an `if` statement.

You should only remove `== True` and change nothing else. Don't add `if` after `assert`.